# Firebase Realtime database persist only one folder?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a project where I'm using Firebase realtime database as my database. Most of my information will be online, but I want to keep some folders offline. As the documentation says, if I write

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true)
```

Any data that I sync from database will be cached, but that's not the behaviour that I want.

Let's say that I have an app where user can create a lists with games

I have 2 folders on my DB root: games and userLists.

In my app I get all games from "games" folder, let the user choose some of them and save under:
userLists/(userId)/(listName).

If I "setPersistenceEnable" as true, all data sync will be kept offline, including games from "game" folder.

I want to keep only the folders under userLists/(userId)/ offline.

Is there anyway  to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: For the future people who may land here. Here's how I solved this:

- Set persistence enabled as true. This will keep data cached, firebase will cache up to 10MB of Cache (depending on your use, your whole database may have less than 10 MB). If you sync more than 10 MB, firebase will erase less used data.

Here comes the trick: get the reference for the folder you want to keep offline. 

Call (folder reference).keepSynced(true).

This will avoid firebase to erase your folder, even if 10MB cache limit is achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible using a simple configuration.  Using the provided API in the default setup, you can either choose to persist any of the data that you get from queries, or you choose not to persist anything at all.

If you need to persist only certain data, you will have to either:

1. Disable persistence, and arrange to persist only certain data on your own (perhaps in a sqlite database)
2. Enable persistence, but only use it for certain queries.  Other queries can go through a different instance of a FirebaseApp where persistence is disabled, or use the REST API directly.